# How to do bulk delete in PHP ElasticSearch API

Tags: php, api, elasticsearch

How to do bulk delete in PHP ElasticSearch API? I know that there are issues with delete by query princip, so I want to try the bulk delete function, but I don't know how to use it. So, I want to know how to use the $client -> bulk method of the ElasticSearch PHP API. Anyone?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Turns out it is very simple:

```
for ($i = 303; $i < 310; $i++) {  
    $params ['body'][] = array(  
        'delete' => array(  
            '_index' => 'er',  
            '_type' => 'state',  
            '_id' => $i  
        )  
    );  
}  
$response = $client -> bulk($params);
```

Comment: still works, i'm using elasticsearch 2.3! thank you!

Comment: Thanks, feel free to upvote the question and all that.